# Не получается из метода сделать Task<result>

Tags: c#

Есть метод он  получает данные из базы, сохраняет их в Datatable и еще я через linq делаю отбор нужного мне количества строк.
Но  возникает ошибка, делать еще один метод как о не эффективно. Где я не прав.

```
 public Task <DataTable> GetDataFromBase(string _connectionString, string qwery,int? _stringout)
        {

           Task<DataTable>  rezulTable = null;

            string connectionString = _connectionString;

            try
            {

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))

                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Ошибка соединения "+e);
                throw;
            }

            var dt = new DataTable();

            //получаем результат запроса в DataTable...
            using (var adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(qwery, connectionString))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }


            // выбираем количество записей

            if (_stringout!=null&&_stringout!=0)// проверяем, что строка не пустая, и не равна 0
            {
             int countRows=(int)_stringout;
             var t = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(countRows);
                // вот тут ошибка
                rezulTable = t.CopyToDataTable();

            }
            else
            {
             rezulTable=dt;
            }

            return rezulTable;

        }
```

Comment: вы нам самим предлагаете гадать, что у вас за ошибка? Может, сэкономите наше время и потратите немного своего - добавите описание вашей ошибки и конкретное место, где она возникает?

Comment: Зачем вы возвращаете `Task`, если ваш метод полностью синхронный. | Есть такой метод: `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov прямо мои мысли слово в слово прочитали :)

Comment: @tym32167  ошибка в том, что я не могу добиться, чтобы компилятор не ругался, а про метод Task.FromResult не слышал, а его логика какая, суть вообще в том,что да мне этот синхронный метод надо сделать асинхронным

Comment: чтобы сделать метод асинхронным не достаточно просто начать возвращать таск, вам нужно внутри метода что то асинхронное делать, например, читать с БД асинхронно.

Comment: @tym32167 да я как раз и думаю, что надо делать что то асинхронно но в своем примере да я достаю данных из базы, но в методах как то я не обнаружил асинхронных реализаций

Comment: ну а вам обязательно надо DataTable читать? Есть куча примеров для чтения своих типов данных с использованием какой-то из ORM, типа EF или Dapper, которые легко читают асинхронно. Ну, или напрямую работайте с SQLCommand, там вроде было где то асинхронное чтение.

Comment: @tym32167 у меня задача выполнять сторонние sql запросы, в данном примере, который я сделал я с этим справлюсь, и фреймворк EF, не удобно использовать ибо мне не нужна объектная модель данных, вопрос только вы выполнении запроса, и отображения его. Ну вот буду тогда искать конструкции где есть асинхронное чтение из базы , кроме ef

Comment: гуглится [вот такое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106131/312041), но я не пробовал, так что на свой страх и риск :)

Comment: @tym32167 Да попробую также сделать как метод расширения

Comment: А в чем ошибка то? непонятно из текста. Переменная t undefined or null? так проверяйте ее перед тем как обращаться к ее членам. А вообще есть замечательный инструмент `Task.ContinueWitch` рекомендую использовать, это эвент..

Comment: И `_stringout!=null&&_stringout!=0` писать слитно - большой грех.. :) String.EmptyOrNull(str) попробуйте

Comment: @NewView Спасибо буду знать))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде определена переменная `rezulTable` типа `Task<DataTable>`. А далее вы пытаетесь присвоить ей значение типа `DataTable`:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
...
rezulTable = t.CopyToDataTable();
...
rezulTable = dt;
```

Чтобы ошибка исчезла можно использовать метод [Task.FromResult](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
rezulTable = Task.FromResult(t.CopyToDataTable());
...
rezulTable = Task.FromResult(dt);
```

Однако, в данном случае это не имеет большого смысла, т. к. ваш код принципиально синхронный. Нужно просто возвращать `DataTable`, изменив сигнатуру метода:

```
public DataTable GetDataFromBase(...)
{
    var resultTable = new DataTable();
    ...
    return resultTable;
}
```

---

Вероятно, у вас возникли проблемы с долгим выполнением этого метода (обращение к БД, загрузка данных), из-за чего, например, подмерзает GUI.

Что можно предпринять?

Первый вариант: запустить внутри метода отдельный поток (задачу) и вернуть её.

```
public Task<DataTable> GetDataFromBase(...)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Task<DataTable> resultTable = null;
        ...
        return resultTable;
    });
}
```

После чего вызывать этот метод следует с `async`:

```
await GetDataFromBase(...);
```

Но такой способ не рекомендуется: [Task.Run Etiquette](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html). <sub>(Хотя [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12602751/5045688) автор статьи сам использует такой способ - как после этого верить людям?..)</sub> Оставьте метод синхронным, а `Task.Run` используйте там, где вызываете этот метод.

---

Другой вариант. Сделаем метод действительно асинхронным. Дело в том, что запуск отдельного потока/задачи следут использовать только для CPU-bound нагрузки, т. е. когда именно процессор занят длительными вычислениями. А у вас идёт IO-bound нагрузка: долго выполняются запросы к БД.

Обший шаблон метода будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetDataFromBaseAsync(string connectionString, string query)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            var resultTable = new DataTable();
            // здесь должен быть код создания колонок в DataTable
            // ...

            while (await reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                var dataRow = resultTable.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < resultTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataRow[i] = reader[i];
                }
                resultTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }
            return resultTable;
        }
    }
}
```

И вот ещё что. Вы выбираете заданное количество строк уже на клиенте (с помощью параметра `_stringout`) - это неэффективно. Это нужно делать непосредственно в sql-запросе (используя ключевое слово `TOP` или `LIMIT` в зависимости от диалекта).

Примечание: у [nullable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)-типов есть свойства HasValue и Value - научитесь их [использовать](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types).

---

Перед написанием ответа я поискал решения асинхронного заполнения дататейбла. Я разочарован. Часто предлагается использовать `Task.Run`. Иногда асинхронно создаётся `DataReader`, а далее загрузка данных выполняется простым вызовом `dataTable.Load(reader)` - то есть синхронно. И такие ответы приняты и заплюсованы. Моя в печали...

Нормальное решение находится по этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106131) (её уже приводили в комментариях).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я решил вопрос методом просто оборачивания в таск, а на счет количества выводимых строк, я исходил из логики, что конечно же ограничение строк лучше делать сразу в базе, ,как вы и с казали, но в моем случае речь идет о произвольном запросе, и тогда Топ в случае с MSSQL и лимит в случае с Ораклом мне придется подставлять в сам запрос автоматически, потому я решил что мне проще отбирать количество строк на клиенте.