# Исключение при вызове таблицы с локальной БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, sql-server-localdb

***Доброго времени суток!***

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня выскакивает вот такое исключение(и как его исправить):

[image: Исключение ExecuteReader. Подключение устанавливается]

Путь соедирнения установлен правильно, через этот метод:

```
    public void OpenConnection(string connectionAdress)
    {
        connect = new SqlConnection(connectionAdress);
        connect.Open();
    }
```

Так же представлю Main:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WorkPlaceDB table = new WorkPlaceDB();
        table.OpenConnection(@"Data Source= 
        (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= 
        D:\Lenovo\Documents\Praktika 
        OOP\Praktika\Day4\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table.GetInfo();
    }
```

Comment: ах, да метод, который на скрине и тот, что под ним являются методами класса работы с этой БД

Comment: вот дока [с примером](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2), если у вас пример этот заработает с вашим подключением, то значит вы не показали нам код, в котором ошибка.

Comment: хотите шутку? прописал в мэйне перед созданием объекта Console.WriteLine("test"); - и вуаля! Все заработало - и как это понимать??

Comment: ну естественно я его убрал, но оно продолжает работать

Comment: я без понятия как это понимать, вы же кода по сути не показали. Того, что вы показали, недостаточно, чтобы хоть что то говорить о вашей ошибке.

Comment: это был весь Main на тот момент + два куска кода из класса, которые были задействованы

Comment: так же можно добавить(забыл), что в классе были определенны два поля: 
        private Database1DataSet table = new Database1DataSet();
        private SqlConnection connect = null;

Comment: если вы на 100% уверены что у вас должно работать, но не работает, то советую пересобирать проект и снова пробовать запустить...но не забывайте что старые ошибки могут вернуться

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по исключению у Вас просто нет постоянного соединения. Попробуйте подобный способ реализации:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source= 
       (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= 
       D:\Lenovo\Documents\Praktika 
       OOP\Praktika\Day4\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     DataTable inv = new DataTable();
     connection.Open();
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
          using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
               if(dr.HasRows)// если есть данные
                    inv.Load(dr);
}
```

Так же можно реализовать данную задачу используя асинхронное чтение

```
private static async Task ReadDataAsync()
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source= 
           (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= 
           D:\Lenovo\Documents\Praktika 
           OOP\Praktika\Day4\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var inv = new DataTable();
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            using (SqlDataReader dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                if (dr.HasRows) // если есть данные
                     while (await dr.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                     {
                          var dataRow = inv.NewRow();
                          for (int i = 0; i < inv.Columns.Count; i++)
                               dataRow[i] = dr[i];
                          inv.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                     }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SqlCommand` и `SqlDataReader` тоже следует обернуть в `using`. `dr.Close` при этом можно убрать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вы правы. Исправил.

Comment: Теперь у меня замечание по поводу асинхронности. Метод `DataTable.Load` загружает данные синхронно. Поэтому ваш метод по большей части синхронный. Хотя, часть данных может быть загружена при выполнении `ExecuteReaderAsync` (подробнее см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/949545/184217)) - тогда асинхронность имеется. Про действительно асинхронную загрузку дататейбла писалось [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/899077/184217).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Если правильно Вас понял, то как-то так должная быть выполнена реализация асинхронного заполнения таблицы (исправил ответ).

Comment: Да, как-то так.